# nested list, display-block and border-radius

Tags: html, css

I'm using a nested list as mentioned in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kfLaZ/1/). I'd thought to be able to use `border-radius: 6px;` at the level of `.csm li` if there `display: inline-block;` was used.

Is there something I have misinterpreted?

Gert

Comment: what do you want to happen? the sub elements tab in instead of out?

Comment: it would be my goal to have just one area that shows the `li` elements where this big element would have rounded corners.

Comment: like I've got in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9BKLF/) but then without the jquery effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to set the `border-radius` on each top-level list item, you can achieve this by changing the `.csm li` descendant selector to be a child selector: `.csm > li` instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/kfLaZ/2/

```
.csm > li {
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #D3EDFB;
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 27em;
    border-radius: 6px;
}
```

---

**Updated** fiddle based on comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kfLaZ/3/

```
.csm {
   list-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #D3EDFB;
    max-width: 27em;
    border-radius: 6px;
 }

.csm > li {
    text-align: right;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 95%;
}
```

Comment: it would be to have a border-radius on the complete set of levels together.